# Reference for formula expressing products of two Fibonacci numbers in Zeckendorf-basis

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

It is well-known folklore that every natural integer has a unique Zeckendorf expansion as a
sum over a finite set of Fibonacci numbers containing no pair of consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

It is easy describe an algorithm for additions and subtractions
of Zeckendorf expansions.

In order to adapt the usual multiplicative algorithm, we need
the Zeckendorf expansion of $f_a\cdot f_b$ for arbitrary
pairs $f_a,f_b$ of Fibonacci numbers.

Using the convention $f_0=1,f_1=2,f_2=3,f_3=5,\ldots,f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ for indices, the following formula (which should not be too difficult to establish) does the job :

$$\begin{align}f_a\cdot f_b = {} & \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (a+b)/4\rfloor}f_{a+b-4k}  \\
& +\min(a,b)\bmod2+(-1)^{1+\min(a,b)}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\vert a-b\vert/4\rfloor} f_{\vert a-b\vert-4k}\\
\end{align}$$
where $x\bmod 2$ is in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$.

The correction (given by the second line) gives rise to the two sequences [A097083](https://oeis.org/A097083) and [A343304](https://oeis.org/A343304) of the OEIS which do not mention
multiplication of Fibonacci numbers.

*Is there a reference for this formula?*

Comment: Gerrit Lekkerkerker - 1952, while  Edouard Zeckendorf -- 1972; but this is a far-far-far- ... - far from the everyday outrageous examples of Stigler's Law of Eponymy in mathematics.

Comment: Using `array` rather than `align` is why $\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\vert a-b\vert/4\rfloor}$ rather than $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\vert a-b\vert/4\rfloor}$ appeared here. I changed that, and also changed `pmod` to `bmod` since you seem to be using it as a binary operation symbol.

Comment: For the first OEIS reference, do you mean [A097083](https://oeis.org/A097083)?

Comment: @BrianHopkins : Yes. Thank you.